# Is there any security concern if I kept password hash on client side?

Tags: password-management, client-side

I have a mobile application that needs to be able to work when the phone is offline. In order to prevent misuse by others when they have a short physical access to the phone the requirement is to authenticate the user every time the application gets opened, i.e. even when offline.

By keeping a hash of the password on the phone I would be able to authenticate the user even when offline. Are there any problems with this approach?

Comment: It is unclear for me what the reason for this requirement is, i.e. what kind of risk should be reduced. If it is somebody accessing or manipulating the data stored offline then just offline authentication will not prevent it - you need encryption of the data instead. A simple offline check of the password can also be bypassed by the offline attacker, i.e. either change the application to bypass the authentication or replace the stored password hash with some other value.

Comment: They just want to prevent someone that pickup their phone to just simply access the content easily.
So it need to be input with some password every time the app is open.

Comment: I've updated your question to integrate the details about the use case.

Comment: Can't you just require a PIN/fingerprint when opening the app? Lots of apps do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first and foremost, check you are hashing and salting the password [correctly](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). It is a lot more critical if the hash is available more easily to attackers. Also keep in mind that even correct hashing can't protect short passwords from determined attackers.

Second of all, if you are using this hash to the authenticate to the online server, you should be aware, that if someone gains access to this hash, they can authenticate to your server. Because the client app can authenticate just using the hash, the attacker can also authenticate using just the hash. You may want to add some nonce to this, that would change on every online login, in order to prevent reuse after a client logs out.

Finally, be aware that you should hash the hash on server side once more (normal SHA2 will suffice), otherwise if someone obtains the hash from your server database, they would be able to authenticate as well. If they obtain a hash of the hash, they can't get the hash that can be used to authenticate.

Comment: Based on the OP question,I think your second statement is incorrect: the local hash is only used to verify the login so unless it can be reversed, it can't be used to authenticate with the server.

Comment: @Stephane That depends on how the password is used to authenticate to the server. If the authentication protocol just uses the hash, not the actual password, then it will be vulnerable to [pass-the-hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_the_hash) type attacks. OTOH if you use *different* hashes (or even just different salts) for local vs. network authentication, then this vulnerability does not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
That's mean if I use actual password when authenticate on server, There shouldn't have any problem right?

Comment: @Stephane I elaboreted that this only applies if the hash is used for authentication, howerver, I find this likely, as he may not want to request the password again if he logs in offline and then later manages to connect to the server.

Comment: @LLF The first issue still applies, otherwise yes, there should not be any problems with storing the hash locally (you should use different salts though).